# Can I remove visible referer from link?

Tags: google-analytics, htaccess, referrer

I use referer info to track which of my campaigns works the best. So instead of

```
<a href="someweb.com">someweb</a>
```

I have a link like

```
<a href="http://someweb.com?utm_source=john&utm_medium=email&utm_content=NAME&utm_campaign=campaing">someweb</a>
```

Now when a user cliks "someweb" the whole URL string is shown in the adressbar. Is this possible to mask/hide somehow? Maybe via .htaccss?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For search engines, putting the correct URL in a [canonical link tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) is the best idea. Then if search engines follow the link, they know the correct URL to show in search results.

Your concern may be with users copying the full URL and pasting elsewhere. A good solution here is to do a 301 redirect back to the canonical page. So when you load the home page, first check the URL parameters and take whatever actions you do already. Then serve a redirect to the root page without the query string.

Comment: If you do a 301 redirect, the campaign tags won't work, since they need to be present in the URL for Google Analytics to capture it.

Comment: So what @yc01 is saying is that what I want to do is not possible?

Comment: @Andreas: If you are using Javascript to handle those parameters, e.g. with Google Analytics, then no the above will not work. You need to load the full page with the parameters still in the URL; 301s are only a server-side solution.

Comment: OK - so I need to do statistics on my own server... Too bad the world is not yet my oyster - but thank you for giving me nice salmon ;-)
I am accepting the answer "no" to my question :-D